# Display pager expand and pager sizes in french with xpages

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I'm working on a project in xpages.
I want to make a view panel components displayed in French.The pager item is already displayed in French but the pager sizes item and pager expand item are written in English.
I would like to know if there is a way to change the language on these two items, either need it I create buttons to achieve the same functionality as these items?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using extension library controls?

Comment: Yes i am using extension library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select in `<xe:pagerExpand` section `All Properties` and put in properties `collapseText` and `expandText` your translated strings. If you have to support several languages then you have to calculate the string.

In `<xe:pagerSizes` you put your translation in property `text`.